# styles.xml style name Theme to Base.Theme

Tags: android, xml, styles

Whenever I am creating a new project in Android Studio it should show the helloWorld print, but it shows nothing unless I go to styles.xml and change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I have to do this every time, How should i solve this problem permanently?